# Grep for a dollar sign within backticks

Tags: linux, shell, unix, grep

I have a file like this

File name : hello.txt

```
{1:ABC}{2:BCD}{3:{108:20140619-2}}{4:
:97A::Hi//12345
:97A::Hi//12345
:93B::Hello//FAMT/00000,
:16S:FIN
-}{5:{CHK:BDG6789}}{S:{ABC:}{DEF:S}{WOM:ONHGRT}}
```

Now basically i'm checking for the existence of $ symbol and as well as :97A: AND im using the below if statement.

```
if [ `grep -c '\$' hello.txt` -gt 0 ] && [ `grep -c ":97A:" hello.txt` -gt 1 ]
then
echo "condition satisfied"
else
echo "condition not satisfied"
fi
```

if i execute this im getting condition satisifed echo statement. But id should be the other way round :( since im putting AND condition. Please help on this.

Comment: What is this supposed to do (in English, not code)?

Comment: basically i will get messages which have $ sign so i was checking the existence of it since it doesn't exist here it should give the echo condition not satisfied rite.?

Comment: what is the output of `grep -c '\$' hello.txt`and `grep -c ":97A:" hello.txt` ? And is it what you expect ?

Answer (score 1):

Replace `grep -c '\$' hello.txt` by `grep -c '\\$' hello.txt` Then it will work as desired.

ex:

```
bash -x test.sh 
++ grep -c '\$' hello.txt
+ '[' 0 -gt 0 ']'
+ echo 'condition not satisfied'
condition not satisfied
```

PS: bash -x is your friend :)

Comment: Hi Tiago pls check my comment

Answer (score 1):

I recommend executing your `grep` commands in a subshell with the `$` syntax, then doing the comparison. In my opinion this is the cleaner way and requires you to be less of an escape artist.

```
if [ $(grep -c '\$' hello.txt) -gt 0 ] && [ $(grep -c ":97A:" hello.txt) -gt 1 ]
then
echo "condition satisfied"
else
echo "condition not satisfied"
fi
```

For your `hello.txt` the output will be:

```
>> bash test.bash 
condition not satisfied
```

Since there's no dollar sign in your file

```
[ $(grep -c '\$' hello.txt) -gt 0 ]
```

will test

```
[ 0 -gt 0 ]
```

and yield false, while

```
[ $(grep -c ':97A' hello.txt) -gt 1 ]
```

will test

```
[ 2 -gt 1 ]
```

and yield true. Finally, false && true will yield false and the second echo statement will be executed.

Answer (score 1):

I also don't understand what you're asking, but from your code I conclude that you have troubles grepping for the dollar sign. I guess you need to escape the backslash as well if you use backticks:

```
$ echo 'foo$bar' > dollar.txt
$ echo 'foo_bar' > no_dollar.txt

$ [ `grep -c '\$' dollar.txt` -gt 0 ] && echo 1
1

$ [ `grep -c '\$' no_dollar.txt` -gt 0 ] && echo 1
1

$ [ `grep -c '\\$' dollar.txt` -gt 0 ] && echo 1
1

$ [ `grep -c '\\$' no_dollar.txt` -gt 0 ] && echo 1

$ [ `grep -c '\\$' no_dollar.txt` -gt 0 ] || echo 0
0
```

alternatively, use `$()` instead of backticks

Comment: You have to double backslashes inside of backquote command substitution because there is an extra level of backslash removal there to allow for backslashed backquotes to act as a nested pair of backquotes. `$()` doesn't require this because it is naturally nestable.

Answer (score 1):

> "i'm checking for the existence of $ symbol"

First condition won't match because there is no "$" sign anywhere in your input, therefore output of first grep is 0.  As 0 isn't greater than 0, the result is "false". Consequently, the second clause won't be executed at all. "Condition is not satisfied" because your requirement for "satisfied" is: input contains both "$" AND ":97A:".

For a result whether grep matched any line, you don't need to count number of matches.

```
if grep -q '\$' file; then ...
```

is a way to use result of grep in a conditional statement without rube-goldbergismns

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk` and reading the file only once:

```
if awk '/[$]/{d++} /:97A:/{o++} END{exit !(d && o>1)}' hello.txt; then
    echo "condition satisfied"
else
    echo "condition not satisfied"
fi
```